# Why is this variable undefined or not returned?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
/*
 * converts a string to geolocation and returns it
 */

function stringToLatLng(string){
    if(typeof string == "string"){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': string}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              console.log("LatLng: "+results[0].geometry.location);
              return results[0].geometry.location;
           } else {
              console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
        });
   }
}
```

the LatLng prints the correct location to the console, but when I write this:

```
var pos = stringToLatLng('New York');
            console.log(pos);
```

I get `undefined` back. Why is that? thanks

Comment: Because `.geocode` is asynchronous

Comment: Why does that imply in this case? I mean LatLng was printed correctly to the console... how can I fix it then? I mean, how can I "wait" until the result is ready?

Comment: you don't need to wait - put all the code that works with results in a callback, as you've already done with `console.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function stringToLatLng(strloc, callback){
    if(typeof string == "string"){
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': strloc}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              callback.call({}, results[0].geometry.location);
           } else {
              console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
           }
        });
   }
}

stringToLatLng('New York', function(pos){
    console.log(pos);
});
```

In your code, when you return, you are actually returning from the function(results, status){..} function, not the stringToLatLng function, as said in the comments its an asynchronous call, so you must use a callback.

Comment: I had tried the above snippet, it is returning the value, it shows up in alert ,but when i try to assign it to some variable or give that alert outside the function it is null again....any help plz...

Comment: i am getting a is null error along with that will it cause some problem in this scenario....

Comment: It is probably because you are trying to use the variable outside the stringToLatLng('New York', function(pos){
    console.log(pos);
}); method, Make sure you are using it directly after the alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
```

ref:
[Javascript geocoding from address to latitude and longitude numbers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984179/javascript-geocoding-from-address-to-latitude-and-longitude-numbers-not-working)