# Getting latitude & longitude values of different places to a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find a set of latitude longitude values and assign it to a variable.
My code looks like this

```
var k = findLattitudeLongitude("Italy");
console.log(k) // comes undefined
function findLattitudeLongitude(input){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': input}, function(results, status) {
      var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        return location;

    });
   }
```

but it comes as undefined. What is the best way to achieve the above requirement. Is there any other method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this variable undefined or not returned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467690/why-is-this-variable-undefined-or-not-returned)

Answer (score 1):

it's strange that the function return undefined, what you can do is to call another function, this way work with me fine, you can pass latitude and longitude params like the code below or the whole object

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function   getlatlan(){
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': "Italy"}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         dosome(results[0].geometry.location.nb,results[0].geometry.location.mb)
     return true;

    ;
}});
}
function dosome(lat,lng){
console.log(lat,lng);
}
getlatlan();
});
```

Comment: console.log and alert boxes always work... try return the value!! That will not work!!

Comment: yes it's return undefined try the code in my answer maybe it will be useful with you

Comment: bt when yu are trying to find  the lang and long of a set of countries.. it wont return all the coordinates..

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you've done is correct.

> **The problem is the response received from `Google geocoder` is taking some time.**

I've created a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bD9yM/1/) for a better understanding.

Comment: so wht is the best way to do this?? Is there anyother way or solution to get thse lattitude longitude values?

Comment: The thing is that I am trying to find a best way to find lattitude longitude values using the function findLattitudeLongitude("Italy") ,

Comment: yup, I understood.  We have to wait till is response from Google geocoder.  Let me try it.  Do you need the value to be returned to k?

Comment: yes!!! thats wht Im trying to get.. I have a value stored in array ["Italy", "Mexico", ... ] and I wanna find the lat long values one by one parsing thru the array.. I just added Italy as sample in my question

Comment: Check the fiddle Ive created.. from your above code.. http://jsfiddle.net/bD9yM/5/  it has 18 elements in country array.. but when the result comes.. alerts for lat long are only for 10 or 12