# geocode does not determine point location exactly on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, geocoding

In google map when I drag a marker `lat()` and `lng()` values shown in textboxes. I want do to like here:

[Coordinates change for every movement](http://www.mygeoposition.com/)

My following code parts work for me. But, when I drag a marker to far, it works, but **in 
 little distances** `lat()` and `lng()` don't change?

How can I solve this issue?

main js codes are:

```
// fill in the UI elements with new position data
            function update_ui(address, lat, lng) {
            $('#lat').val(lat);
            $('#lng').val(lng);
        }


 // move the marker to a new position, and center the map on it
        function update_map(geometry) {
            map.fitBounds(geometry.viewport)
            marker.setPosition(geometry.location)
        }
```

And geocode:

```
geocoder.geocode(request, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // Google geocoding has succeeded!
                if (results[0]) {
                    // Always update the UI elements with new location data
                    update_ui(results[0].formatted_address, results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng())

                    // Only update the map (position marker and center map) if requested
                    if (update) { update_map(results[0].geometry) }
                } else {
                    // Geocoder status ok but no results!?
                    alert("Error occured. Please try again.");
                }
            } else {
                // Google Geocoding has failed. Two common reasons:
                //   * Address not recognised (e.g. search for 'zxxzcxczxcx')
                //   * Location doesn't map to address (e.g. click in middle of Atlantic)

                if (type == 'address') {
                    alert("Sorry! We couldn't find " + value + ". Try a different search term, or click the map.");
                } else {
                    alert("Sorry! We couldn't find " + value + ". Try a different search term, or click the map.");
                    update_ui('', value.lat(), val.lng())
                }
            };
        });
```

**Edit:**

When I drag a marker very little, coordinates do not change, but after some movement they change. Here is jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhoonbey/wwdE9/

Comment: Do you have a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?  Can't do anything with pictures.  What is the value of update?  What does update_map do?

Comment: No, sorry, I can not add my code to jsfiddle. I edited my question, added that function.

Now I am learning about. google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.ROOFTOP. It is type that geocoder find points exactly. but I cannot set that type to geocoder.

Comment: @geocodezip, i placed my code to jsfiddle and edited my question. Can you help me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the marker's position through a geocoder.

A geocoder takes a raw lat/lng location and tries to map it to an address. This could be a street or a town or a region. The results that the Google geocoder return include the address text, plus the location of that address.

You're displaying the location that the geocoder returns. As the user moves the marker around regions with a low density of potential addresses, you're going to see aliasing. That means that the various raw locations that the user 'selects' will reverse geocode down to the same address being returned by the geocoder.

Thus, it will appear as if the lat/lng of the marker is not changing, when what you're actually doing is displaying the lat/lng of the geocoded address.

Note, that site that you linked to doesn't do any geocoding when it displays position information.

Comment: And what can I use that, when move marker then coordinates change for every point in map. Because I save markers coordinates in database, then on load them, they don't seem in real places. they run away.

Comment: That sounds like a totally different question - so ask a new SO question.

Comment: Cannot do what? I don't understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English.
 I need to show changed coordinates when marker move a little, but with my code i can not get that result. Is it possible to do it with Google geocoder, generally? If possible, how can I change my code, if not, i will ask new question.

Comment: You can't rely on the geocoder, as I explained. However, you already  have the raw location since that's what you passed into the geocoder in the first place, so just use that!