# Get latlng from different addresses using PHP & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps Geocoding function. I got some addresses which I load into a PHP variable. The addresses are defined by a textbox which the user can type in a zip code. I give an example:

A user types in the textbox a postal code (12345 for example). Now it loads addresses from the system (this is internal - but it works to load the addresses). And then it display some addresses. These addresses are now stored in a `PHP` variable (`$address`). And now I want to get the `latitude` and `longitude` from these different addresses.

I had a look at this thread: [Javascript geocoding from address to latitude and longitude numbers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984179/javascript-geocoding-from-address-to-latitude-and-longitude-numbers-not-working)

I used this code from the article:

```
var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
alert(latitude + ' - ' + longitude);
```

This is nice but it just give me the `latlng` from the address I typed in the textbox, not from all the addresses I got.

Is there a way to get the `latitude` and `longitude` from all the different addresses? If yes, could someone please explain me? I'm new to `JavaScript` and `Google Maps API`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "from all the different addresses?" what do you mean? Anyway, you are at the correct direction.

Comment: With this I mean the addresses which are loaded, display and then stored in a PHP variable

Comment: JavaScript is client-side, PHP is server-side. You may want AJAX. or just use PHP Google Maps API ?

Comment: If it's possible I don't want to go with AJAX. I want to go like I started :)

Comment: have you tried `results[1]`, `results[2]`, ...?

Comment: Yep, but then there is no alert

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example [given here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).
See the code below for specific functionality:

```
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
function findAddress(address) 
{
    // You can pass the address from your PHP to Javascript using AJAX. Here, I'm assuming that you have done it and that you're passing it as a string argument to this function
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
             return position: results[0].geometry.location;
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Show some message that the address cannot be found on map.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I got this but is this really to get `latitude` and `longitude` from the addresses which are loaded? I thought this is just to create a marker with a specific position?

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've edited the code. Now it will return you the location (latlng) of the address you've provided.

Comment: The address is now stored in `'address': address`? So I can load the PHP variable `$address` to JavaScript `'address': address`? Am I right or have I missunderstood it?

Comment: No, the function returns the latlng Use it like this
`//Your code that fetches the address from PHP via AJAX.`

`var latlng = findAddress(address);`
Now you can do whatever you want to with that string.
Please mark it as an answer if it solves your question.

Comment: Mh, thank you for your support but I still don't get the latlng from the addresses :/

Comment: What exactly are you getting when you execute that function? Make sure you've included the Google Maps JS file into your page.

Comment: I've included the JS file. I don't get anything. I want to alert the latlng from every single address but I don't get an alert. If I use my code above I get the LatLng from the address I typed in...